# 深層学習の計算に用いるGPUとしてはどれくらいの性能のものが最低でも必要なんでしょう？

Tags: 機械学習, 深層学習, gpu

深層学習の計算に用いるGPUとしてはどれくらいの性能のものが最低でも必要なんでしょう？
（ローカル：自分のパソコンで計算する場合です）

Comment: この場合、対象とする問題・課題や実行する作業内容・量と掛けられる時間などの諸条件が明記されていないと意味が無いのでは？

Comment: 現実的には予算で決まってくるのではないでしょうか？予算内で購入できる最新のものを検討されてはいかがでしょうか？